# How to properaly escape using mysql / sqlstring in Node.js in bulk INSERT?

Tags: mysql, node.js, escaping

I am using these node modules:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const SqlString = require('sqlstring');
```

I read JSON from files and parse the JSON into an nested array.  I then pass the nested array into a bulk MySQL INSERT.

This works fine for 25 out of 26 files and loads over 500 records.  One file has 21 JSON records and only fails the following record:

```
[
    {
        "abstract": "... AWS Shared responsibility model:​ https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/shared-responsibility-model/; Enabling object-level logs in S3:​ ...",
        "title": "Defeating a Cloud Breach Part 1"
    }
]
```

I have isolated the problem to the "abstract" field.

I have tried escaping the value of "abstract" prior to laoding into an array using both connection.escape() and SqlString.escape() from both the "mysql" and "sqlString" modules, respectively.  Neither case corrects whatever is causing the INSERT to fail.

The INSERT fails by returning "undefined" irrrespective of the methods.  A successful INSERT returns something like:

```
OkPacket {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 4,
  insertId: 142,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: '&Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 0
}
```

The "abstract" column within the MySQL table is of type "text" and there are many other records whose length exceed the problem record above.

**SqlString** -- As I iterate through the JSON key / values, I tried escaping the string prior to placing within the nested array.

Example:  abstract = SqlString.escape(value))

I have also tried on the entire INSERT statement, thus:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO tbl (abstract,title,url,key_word) VALUES ?";

sql = SqlString.format(sql, [dbVals]);

var query = client.query(sql, function(err, result) {
console.log(result);
});
```

Obviously in the clode above "client" is an instance of the "mysql" CONNECTIONS (which is why I have also tried suing the mysql.escape() and client.escape() in place of SqlString.escape())

But I get precisely the same result and **only on this one record**.

I have confirmed that this content is the issue in that I have both deleted the record above and have set the value of abstract to empty string and in BOTH of those instances the bulk INSERT succeeds.

I would appreciate a second set of eyes.  Better still, I would appreciate guidance on what I am doing wrong to properaly escape content so that this will not be a future concern.

Thank you.

EDIT:  Additional detail added to question.

Comment: Do you have an error message? Does your `abstract` text fit in the column in your table. What are the lines of code doing the doomed INSERT operation? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your issue might be with your schema. Also confusing: one portion of your example indicates you are trying to insert 4 values `(abstract,title,url,key_word)`, but your payload only contains 2 fields - not clear on that discrepancy or how defaults/nulls are handled on the DB side.

Testing with the example payload you provided, using a best-guess schema, I encountered no issue. Since your payload only includes 2 fields, my testing only includes those fields. Examples for each component below to compare to your own.

Feel free to share additional details on your DB, table schema, and fields if you're still encountering issues. The `charset` of your DB, table, and field might be a good detail to investigate as well.

**DATABASE DETAILS**
MySQL v5.7.12

```sql
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `abstract` text,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

**NODE**

```js
// 
// other require items here as well depending on file location in project
// 
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST || '127.0.0.1',
  user: process.env.DB_USER || 'local_user',
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'local_password',
  database: process.env.DB_NAME || 'local_database',
  multipleStatements: true, 
  charset: 'utf8mb4' // necessary if you might need support for emoji characters
});

let entries = [
  {
    "abstract": "An easy one",
    "title": "Defeating a Cloud Breach Part 0"
  },
  {
    "abstract": "... AWS Shared responsibility model:​ https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/shared-responsibility-model/; Enabling object-level logs in S3:​ ...",
    "title": "Defeating a Cloud Breach Part 1"
  },
  {
    "abstract": "Another easy one",
    "title": "Defeating a Cloud Breach Part 2"
  }
]
let keys = Object.keys(entries[0]);
let values = entries.map( obj => keys.map( key => obj[key]));
let sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl (' + keys.join(',') + ') VALUES ?;';
db.query(sql, [values], function (error, results) {
  if (error) console.log(error.code);
  console.log(results);
});
```

**THE RESULTS**

```js
OkPacket {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 3,
  insertId: 1,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: '&Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 0
}
```

[image: db screenshot]

Comment: Thank you, dusthaines!

It was charset "'utf8mb4' in the Connection string that did the trick.  I have no idea what character(s) were creating the issue, but that was the fix.